# Netbeans not allowing creation of META-INF package because of the hyphen

Tags: java, netbeans, package, meta-inf

This is probably a very stupid question, but for some reason netbeans claims creating a package named META-INF is invalid, and won't let me do it. Anyone know how to get around this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: To create a maven archetype

Answer (score 0):

Really Netbeans doesn't allow you create META-INF folder via IDE. But you can do it via OS (Operating System). Go to the "src" folder, via OS, and create META-INF folder.